# Dozer Mapping between primitive datatype and Custom object?

Tags: java, collections, mapping, dozer

I have the following scenario :

```
Class A{
  private List<Long> longList;
  //getter and setter
}

Class B{
  private List<C> listC;
  //getter and setter
}

Class C{
  private Long id;
  //getter and setter
}
```

Now, I want to convert between `longList` and `C`. I found the following mapping :

```
<mapping>
  <class-a>A</class-a>
  <class-b>B</class-b>
  <field>
    <a>longList</a>
    <b>listC</b>
    <a-hint>java.lang.Long</a-hint>
    <b-hint>C</b-hint>
  </field>
</mapping>
```

I am not sure whether the above mapping is the proper solution or not.
Can I set up a mapping between `long` and `C` , such that long gets mapped to `C.id` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try mapping Long to C like so:

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>A</class-a>
    <class-b>B</class-b>
    <field>
        <a>longList</a>
        <b>listC</b>
    <field>
</mapping>

<mapping>
    <class-a>java.lang.Long</class-a>
    <class-b>C</class-b>
    <field>
        <a>this</a>
        <b>id</b>
    <field>
</mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks man. It did worked. I thought **this** would be for maps only.But it works in this case also.

Comment: I get the same problem. But this is not working for me (Dozer 5.3.2).
Problem is inverted, I need convert C to Long